# Performance - RDD vs High level APIs (dataframes)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We can write spark code/transformations using RDD (low level API), Dataframe, SQL. As per my understanding dataframe/SQL is more performant (due to tungsten, catalyst optimizer) than low level API(RDD), hence it is recommended to use Dataframe/SQL.

Internally spark converts all the code to RDD. So even if we write Dataframes, internally it is converted to RDD. So how is using high level APIs beneficial?

Comment: The additional metadata in Dataframes are what helps in optimizing the query.

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-dataset

Comment: I get that. My question is, internally everything gets converted to RDD. So how datafarme/sql helps in performance?

Comment: If you look at the type Dataframe = Dataset[Row] type. and Datasets are handled using encoders which are faster than plain java serialization used in RDD. Metadata helps in query optimization. "Encoder handles conversions between JVM objects and tables, which is faster than Java serialization."

Comment: My understanding is that everything in spark (dataframe, SQL,dataset) is internally converted as RDD for execution. Is this the right understanding?

Comment: Interestingly, noone mentioned WSCG (Whole Stage Code gen), which is only possible in Dataset/Dataframe world and provides massive improvement vs volcano execution model.

Comment: could you please elaborate on WSCG vs volcano execution model wrt performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the Spark Optimizer - `Catalyst` - which applies optimization strategies to DF's or DS's. Not to RDD's. In addition you process a whole row / tuple whatever you want to call it with an RDD, not so with DF's or DS's, they can be used by Spark in a columnar fashion.

Comment: got it. My understanding is that everything in spark (dataframe, SQL,dataset) is internally converted as RDD for execution. Is this the right understanding? if yes, then everything is RDD at the end, so how dataframe/datasets can be faster?

Comment: Columnar aspect. Rdd whole record processed.

Comment: finally, My understanding is that everything in spark (dataframe, SQL,dataset) is internally converted as RDD for execution. Is this the right understanding?

Comment: Not totally, converted as in? to RDD? RDD is underlying but DS and DF have metadata that Catalyst can optimize. If memory serves correct the join order in yours tatement for an RDD is as you specifiy, but for DF DS it can decide on what table should be driver.

Answer (score 1):

Dataframes are not faster than RDDs. As you said, everything is converted to RDDs, so with RDDs you can theoretically achieve greater performance, but with Dataframes you can write good old SQL and allow Spark to handle partitioning and other optimizations. When you pass SQL spark may see what you need at the end and try to optimize it. Also writing performant RDD code requires knowledge of Spark internals to some extent. One example of low-level api in RDD is that you can specify a partitioning function for your RDD, but with Dataframe API you can only use a limited number of partitioning strategies like hash or range partitioning.

Comment: faster or not faster? Earlier answers suggested dataframes are faster than RDDs.

Comment: RDDs are theoretically faster, but Dataframes are usually faster due to big number of built-in optimizations, which you would not apply to RDDs due to lack of time, knowledge or both